# Flutter path_provider get _CastError

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the path_provider: ^2.0.3 plugin to get the path of the ApplicationDocumentsDirectory on Android. But I got always the same error "Exception has occured. _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)".

I call it directly in the main. Here is a code snippet:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() async {
  final appDocumentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); 
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.green.shade800,
        accentColor: Colors.green.shade600,
      ),
      home: MyAppPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

The exception occured inside of the path_provider source files. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try a flutter clean and then flutter pub get.
   If this does not solve it try.
2. Do Flutter widget binding.
   Something like this in your code.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final appDocumentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); 
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Second point did it. Do you also know why do I need to call that init to get the path_provider working? I didn't find that initialization in any example snippets of the path_provider....